# Consul support or alternative for 2 nodes

Tags: consul, consensus, raft

I want to use consul for a 2-node cluster. Drawback is there's no failure tolerance for two nodes :

https://www.consul.io/docs/internals/consensus.html

Is there a way in Consul to make a consistent leader election with only two nodes? Can Consul Raft Consensus algorithm be changed?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why can't you add another node?

Comment: It's expensive. They are two 15k$ nodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're limited to 2 machines *of this type*, because they are expensive. Consider acquiring three or five cheaper machines to run your orchestration layer.

To answer protocol question, no, there is no way to run a two-node cluster with failure tolerance in Raft. To be clear, you *can* safely run a two-node cluster just fine - it will be available and make progress like any other cluster. It's just when one machine goes down, because your fault tolerance is zero you will lose availability and no longer make no progress. But safety is never compromised - your data is still persisted consistently on these machines.

Even outside Raft, there is no way to run a two-node cluster and guarantee progress upon a single failure. This is a fundamental limit. In general, if you want to support f failures (meaning remain safe and available), you need 2f + 1 nodes.

There are non-Raft ways to improve the situation. For example, Flexible Paxos shows that we can require both nodes for leader election (as it already is in Raft), but only require a single node for replication. This would allow your cluster to continue working in *some* failure cases where Raft would have stopped. But the worst case is still the same: there are always failures that will cause any two-node cluster to become unavailable.

That said, I'm not aware of any practical flexible paxos implementations anyway.

Considering the expense of even trying to hack up a solution to this, your best bet is to either get a larger set of cheaper machines, or just run your two-node cluster and accept unavailability upon failure.

Comment: May I add a node with the only purpose to vote for the consensus in consul? A cheap node / service to allow to reach a consensus. A node that will never be a candidate.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. Although, again I don't think you'll find something like that. However, it may be helpful to get some more details: what is the data that you want consensus on?

Comment: Only for leader election.

Comment: @AlfonsoTienda: That's leader election between the two main nodes? What happens if they both think they're the leader? Sorry to sound nit picky, but the more details the better. :) Depending on what you want to do (e.g., with an elected leader), there can be alternative solutions. Distributed consensus is actually quite strong in its guarantees, and if you don't need _all_ of them, something simpler can work.

Comment: If I have 3 nodes and one goes down, I have 2 nodes. How can raft then work if it requires an odd number of nodes to adjudicate/achieve quorum?

Comment: @Marc Raft does not require an odd number of nodes to work, it requires an odd number to have any failure tolerance. To support 0 failures, 1 node is required. To support 1 failure, 3 nodes are required. To support 2 failures, 5 nodes are required. The even numbers between are, in a sense, excess. In your scenario, 2 nodes constitute a majority out of 3 and therefore can make decisions amongst themselves without risking safety. If _another_ node went down, then progress would halt. If you start with 2 nodes, you're as-if you had 3 nodes with 1 permanently unavailable.

Comment: IMO the easiest way to think about safety is in terms of overlap. You may safely elect a leader as long as the voters overlap with the set of prior replica nodes. Imagine you have 3 nodes and 1 is down, so 2 are managing replication; then all of them go down. If you require 2 of them to vote for a new leader, then at least one of them was part of the previous replica set and can positively approve that the new leader has the most up-to-date information. There is no majority that does not overlap the prior replica set.

Comment: By contrast, imagine there are 5 nodes and only 2 are available. If you want to require a majority to elect a leader (i.e., 3 nodes), then there do exist majorities that do not intersect the available 2. Therefore, those 2 are not permitted to continue replication. Flexible paxos is the idea that you can tweak this to allow those 2 to replicate, but in return you will require more than a majority of nodes vote on a leader to ensure at least one of those 2 is present in that vote. A majority for leader election and a majority for replication is sort of the 'sweet spot' in the middle.

Comment: If I have 2 nodes and one goes down surely the final node has a “majority” to elect itself?

Comment: @Marc 1 is not a majority of 2. It's trivial to see that if you have 2 nodes and communication is broken between them, from each node's perspective the other node has gone down. It would be quite wrong for each to decide it has a majority - both would elect themselves as leader. I'd recommend reading flexible paxos more to get better intuition.

Comment: Your comment is valid for a network split which is IMO very rare. In the much more common scenario of a single node down the majority is 1/1. Indeed [K3S supports HA](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/ha/) with 2 nodes. We are coming from a different angle - consider that when one node goes down the requirement is not necessarily that the cluster operates fully as normal but that all pods/services on the up node are still available/reachable via ingress. If everything runs as a DaemonSet this should be achievable.

Comment: @Marc Whether or not something is "rare" does not preclude it from happening. And partitions are much more common than you might think, **lots** of failure modes look like partitions. You're arguing with proven theoretical results, I'm not sure what else to say. If you want to do a _membership change_ so the total participants goes from 2 to 1, that's fine. But again, how many failures (things you _don't_ necessarily control) you tolerate is `2f + 1` for Raft, full stop. You can perform non-linearizable reads when quorum is lost, but that's not what the word 'available' means to Raft.

Answer (score 2):

Talking about changing the protocol, there is impossibility proof by FLP which states that consensus cannot be reached if systems are less than `2f + 1` for `f` failures (fail-stop). Although, safety is provided but progress (liveness) cannot be ensured.

I think, the options suggested in earlier post are the best.

Answer (score 2):

The choice of leader election on top of the Consul’s documentation itself requires 3 nodes. This relies on the health-checks mechanism, as well as the sessions. Sessions are essentially distributed locks automatically released by TTL or when the service crashes.

To build 2-node Consul cluster we have to use another approach, supposedly called **Leader Lease**. Since we already have Consul KV-storage with CAS support, we can simply write to it which machine is the leader before the expiration of such and such time. As long as the leader is alive and well, it can periodically extend it's time. If the leader dies, someone will replace it quickly. For this approach to work, it is enough to synchronize the time on the machines using ntpd and when the leader performs any action, verify that it has enough time left to complete this action.

A key is created in the KV-storage, containing something like “node X is the leader before time Y”, where Y is calculated as the current time + some time interval(T). As a leader, node X updates the record once every T/2 or T/3 units of time, thereby extending it's leadership role. If a node falls or cannot reach the KV-storage, after the interval(T) its place will be taken by the node, which will be the first to discover that the leadership role has been released.
CAS is needed to prevent a race condition if the two nodes simultaneously try to become a leader. CAS Specifies to use a Check-And-Set operation. This is very useful as a building block for more complex synchronization primitives. If the index is 0, Consul will only put the key if it does not already exist. If the index is non-zero, the key is only set if the index matches the ModifyIndex of that key.